# Am I missing something on retrieving GPS Current Location?

Tags: java, android, gps

I recently began developing an app, and I've spent the last few days working on the GPS part to obtain the user's address.

The issue is that if I run the app in Android Studio Emulator and change the address on the map, it appears correctly on a Toast and in the String variable I created to store the address, as shown in the screenshot below, but if I build the APK and run it on a Smartphone, the Toast does not appear and the String variable remains empty.

Is there something in my code that I'm forgetting? I'll paste the code for someone to review below.

```
public class FragmentT1_Agora extends Fragment {

   View view;    
   LocationManager locationManager;
   String moradaAtual; // Current Address
   
   private Button btEnviar;

   public FragmentT1_Agora() {
       // Required empty public constructor
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_t1_agora, container, false);
   
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
       }
        
       locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 3, mLocationListener);

       return view;
   }

   private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> moradas = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                moradaAtual = moradas.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Morada: " + moradaAtual, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
}
```

I've left out the code that isn't related to the GPS.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does your manifest have ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
`?

Comment: Are location services enabled on the phone?

Comment: @Strom Yes, my manifest has that permission

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, the location services are enabled

Comment: Hi, can help to share the code part which on granted permission from the user?

Comment: @PutraNugraha It's on the code I've posted before ->

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
       }

Comment: It seems the code to trigger the permission dialog, how about the code on how you handle the permission granted/denied?

Comment: @PutraNugraha Hm, I think I haven't made that part yet

Comment: Lets try to add that part and when permission was granted, can add `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` there

Comment: I know that maybe my question is stupid, but do you have the GPS signal at your test place? You know that the GPS_PROVIDER returns a fix only when the GPS finds it..